# taking screenshot of sql query result from java

Tags: java

Is there any possibility to take the screenshot of sql query result in sql developer from java code.
If possible please suggest me the solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get screenshots using the `Robot` class

e.g.

```
BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );

 // Save as JPEG
 File file = new File("screencapture.jpg");
 ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", file);
```

You can define the Rectangle area that you want to capture

P.S

But if you just want to get a screenshot it would be better to use some tool like snipper or something else to get the screenshot rather than using java programs